# Role of a Wali for a boy

Tags: wali

The role of a Wali is most discussed with respect to girls/women until marriage.

However, a minor boy has a wali as well, and the succession of the father becomes relevant when the father dies early.

The wali, father or not, has to care for the child. Is there a particular occasion when this role ends or does it just cease to be significant?

Comment: Depends on what role of the guardian you are asking about. For example guardianship over an orphan's property extends till puberty and possibly after that until the person develops  sound judgement, verse [4:6](https://quran.com/4/6?translations=20) is relevant here. Guardianship of education, training or disciplining etc. for a father can extend forever.